# modx - issue with capital case letters in alias

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution, modx-templates

I have a page in modx for which I have created a symlink to make available the same page in bit lengthy URL also. My problem is I need to have symlink alias URL with some capital case letters.

I tried to save it with proper capital case letters modx is automatically converting it to lowercase letters.

Comment: There's a prior discussion on the topic here with solutions - http://forums.modx.com/thread/28808/case-sensitive-urls-not-working

Comment: Hi Phil thanks for your reply . but in that forum they are talking about making case insensitive url , i need to have case sensitive url.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for friendly_alias_lowercase_only system setting (system settings » core » Fiendly URL » friendly_alias_lowercase_only ). It is true by default. You need false.
This option cancels automatic alias lowercasing for all pages.

Another way to solve this problem: page «Freeze URI» setting (page » settings tab » Freeze URI). You can define any custom uri for a page via this setting. It is good if you try to change uri for a few pages.